# useEffect and reactStrictMode

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have this challenge where I want to load parts of an array to a new array called "loadedData" and only display the loadedData, as the component is very heavy.

However, on first load, I have had so many issues with the first load, as the useEffect seems to mess it up. The first load will happen twice, and push the first data on the array one time per render. If I remove "reactStrictMode" it works as it's supposed but I do not want to "cheat" without understanding the implications. Someone with a better understanding than me put it there for a reason..

During the initial load, the isLoading state does not prevent the second run from happening - which is the recommendation I tend to get in other threads related to this issue.

Anyone got a clue why the first useEffect ignores the isLoading state and what to do about it?

```
  // Try to load what is visible, but not more
  const [loadedData, setLoadedData] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

const addMoreData = async () => {
    if (loadedData.length >= data.length) return;

    const startIndex = loadedData.length;
    const preferredLoadLength = 1;

    const endIndex = startIndex + preferredLoadLength;

    const newData = data.slice(startIndex, endIndex);

    setLoadedData((prev) => [...prev, ...newData]);
  };

  // Check on mount and after a fetch to see if the table is already scrolled to the bottom and immediately needs to fetch more data
  useEffect(() => {
    const { scrollHeight, scrollTop, clientHeight } = tableContainerRef.current;
    if (
      scrollHeight == clientHeight &&
      scrollTop == 0 &&
      loadedData.length < data.length
    ) {
      const addNewDataFunction = async () => {
        if (isLoading) {
          return;
        }
        setIsLoading(true);
        await addMoreData();
        setIsLoading(false);
      };
      addNewDataFunction();
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [data.length, loadedData.length, isLoading]);
```

Comment: If you want your side effect run only once, then you dont need to pass any dependency array,  secondly your  you are changing the isloading state in your side effect,  and it is the dependency array also, it will causes a loop actually but you have used a condition in your side effect thats why its runs only twice.

Comment: normally the isloading state is used to display a loader in the components view, so you dont need to write a condition for it, just remove it from the dependency array

Comment: Yeah, but i'm trying to use it to avoid my "loadedData" array to get populated twice on the initial render. right now, my array becomes like this [1,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10....]. It basically failed the first run and works after that... I dont understand why the first run is different

Comment: @AhmerSaud when you put an empty dep array, this won't prevent useEffect from running twice when the component mounts, also including `isLoading` is useless I agree but this won't cause an infinite render since it is a boolean, not immutable, the infinite render will occur only if it is an object or an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change this line in `addMoreData` function

```js
setLoadedData((prev) => [...prev, ...newData]);
```

To

```js
setLoadedData([...loadedData, ...newData]);
```

This will make the state update based on its value during the current render and since the second time `useEffect` runs the component didn't rerender yet so changes made by the first one are not reflected yet therefore `loadedData` is not updated yet.

When you updated with the functional form, `prev` is the real-time value of the state and what you are encountering is expected in development using strict mode.

Finally, get rid of `isLoading` it won't help fixing that.

**Note:** using the functional form of setState is more recommended but not in `useEffect` when strict mode is enabled since the hook runs twice when the component mounts.
Also when you include `data.length` and `loadedData.length` in the dependency array, this will make `useEffect` fire each time one of those values change.

Comment: Thanks man! I have been stuck and coming back to this small issue for multiple weeks, and not having felt satisfied as it's buggy in development but working in prod. Much appreciated spotting that.

Comment: @OscarEkstrand you are welcome, but the most important that you understand why it does work ^^